# UIScrollview questions

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to implement a uiscrollview with small images.

1. I need that uiscrollview last image in every end remain in the center when scroll finishes, leaving one side empty. Now last image remain in the sides when scroll finishes.
2. I need to know which image is in the center of the scollview, to apply a shadow on it,

   ```
   jugadorSlide.pagingEnabled = YES;
   NSError *error = nil;
   fotosJugadores = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: @"/Users/exular/Developer/GBC/exular/GBC/Caras/" error: &error];

   NSInteger numberOfViews = [fotosJugadores count];
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {

       UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[fotosJugadores objectAtIndex:i]];
       CGFloat yOrigin = i * myImage.size.width;
       UIImageView *awesomeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height)];
       awesomeView.alpha = 0.5;
       awesomeView.image = myImage;
       [self.jugadorSlide addSubview:awesomeView];
       awesomeView=nil;
   }
   jugadorSlide .contentSize = CGSizeMake(65 * numberOfViews,78);
   jugadorSlide.layer.cornerRadius = 11;
   jugadorSlide.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
   ```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow the first and last image to be in the center just add an empty space before the first image and after your last image. In other words: start your `yOrigin` at `65` and add `65` to the `contentSize` width (I am assuming that `65` is your images width):

```
...
CGFloat yOrigin = i * myImage.size.width + 65;
...
jugadorSlide.contentSize = CGSizeMake(65 * numberOfViews + 65,78);
...
```

To find out which image is in the center add the following inside the UIScrollViewDelegate method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:`.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    int currentIndex = roundf(scrollView.contentOffset.x / 65) - 1;
    UIImageView *currentImage = [scrollView viewWithTag:currentIndex];
}
```

To easily get the currentImage, add tags to your images when you create them:

```
...
awesomeView.tag = i;
...
```